# What MySQL index(s) to add where only one of two columns are non-null

Tags: mysql

I have an app where user profile fields (represented using either radio or checkbox options or a date chooser) are defined in the database, and users make selections from available options or choose a date for each field. I have chosen to use one table to represent user field selections for both option and date field types, so for each row either `sel_id` or `sel_date` will be null.

```
CREATE TABLE user_profile_selection (
    id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    field_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    sel_id INT UNSIGNED,
    sel_date DATE
);
```

Queries to find users based on profile selections make a join per field/option and can have multiple compound condition sets to find users that match any of one or more criteria sets. There is a UI for building complex queries.

For an example query, find users with (field 1 - option 1 or 2; and field 7 date before 2019-12-17) OR (field 1 - no selection; and field 7 date between 2019-12-04 and 2019-12-10):

```
SELECT user.id, user.username FROM user
    LEFT JOIN user_profile_selection AS upf_1_o_1 ON upf_1_o_1.user_id=user.id AND upf_1_o_1.field_id=1 AND upf_1_o_1.sel_id=1
    LEFT JOIN user_profile_selection AS upf_1_o_2 ON upf_1_o_2.user_id=user.id AND upf_1_o_2.field_id=1 AND upf_1_o_2.sel_id=2
    LEFT JOIN user_profile_selection AS updf_7 ON updf_7.user_id=user.id AND updf_7.field_id=7
    LEFT JOIN user_profile_selection AS upf_1_ns ON upf_1_ns.user_id=user.id AND upf_1_ns.field_id=1
    WHERE (
        (upf_1_o_1.user_id IS NOT NULL OR upf_1_o_2.user_id IS NOT NULL)
        AND
        updf_7.sel_date<"2019-12-17"
    ) OR (
        upf_1_ns.user_id IS NULL AND updf_7.sel_date>="2019-12-04" AND updf_7.sel_date<="2019-12-10"
    );
```

Now I am trying to figure out the most efficient index or indexes to add to `user_profile_selection` to support these user queries.

I could add one index that spans `(user_id, field_id, sel_id, sel_date)` and add `sel_id IS NULL` conditions where matching dates, and add `sel_date IS NULL` as a join condition when joining based on `sel_id`. I think `sel_id` would have to come before `sel_date` in the index so the dates are all together in one branch of the index tree for matching date ranges.

Or I could add separate `(user_id, field_id, sel_id)` and `(user_id, field_id, sel_date)` indexes, which may be better as for any given `field_id` there will only be either rows with `sel_id` values or rows with `sel_date` values, however each index will refer to all the rows of the other field type under the null value.

Are there performance and storage considerations for preferring one approach over the other, and do both sets of considerations favour the same option or is there a tradeoff? It may be better to use separate tables for option and date values in any case, but any insights will be appreciated.

Comment: your WHERE clause leads me to believe that your LEFT JOIN AS updf_7 is not meant to be a LEFT JOIN but rather a full join?

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` to see the execution plan. In my experience, MySQL typically uses just a single index for a table reference; where MySQL might use a range scan operation to exclude rows that can't be returned, adding a `OR` condition that allows rows outside the range to be returned, that disables MySQL from using the index. Sometimes, we re-write queries with conflicting `OR` blocks as two separate queries, combined with a UNION or UNION ALL set operator.